# Display Documents in an IFrame

Tags: iframe, internet-explorer, doc

A colleague set up an intranet application where the users can upload documents. These documents are displayed afterwards in an IFRAME using <IFRAME src="document.doc"></IFRAME> - of course this only works in IE. While this works with some users, others (including myself) do not see the document, but rather a download dialogue allowing them to download the document.

I vaguely remember that there was a recent security issue with displaying MS Office documents in IFRAMES, but could not find any information whether there was a security update blocking this. Anyone here who has a clue?

I am not looking for alternatives for the IFrame, I just want to know why some users are displayed the download box while other users see the inline document.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you get a download dialogue instead of displaying the document inline in an iframe, then:

1. you probably haven't installed the Office Web Components. You can change the components Office has installed from its Add/Remove Programs entry in the Control Panel. But,
2. **DON'T**. There have been endless security holes in OWC. Installing a plugin means a great deal of new net-facing code and subsequently a great potential for exploitable bugs, especially in software that wasn't originally intended to be net-facing like Office.

Install the absolute minimum number of plugins you can get away with (these days usually just Flash). Don't install every plugin an application offers you, don't install a PDF plugin, and definitely don't install a load of plugins for Office documents.

Is viewing an Office document in a little annoying scrolly box tucked into a web page really compelling enough to justify the risk? I suggest that no, it's in fact much much *less* usable than just downloading the document to the desktop and opening it in a proper document editor/viewer.

Answer (score 0):

You might consider an RTE like [CKEditor](http://ckeditor.com/).  It allows the user to cut-and-paste from Word (I assume you are primarily concerned with Word docs given your problem description) and then to view and edit.  CKEditor claims to be "compatible with all major browsers."